# i was making a Godot platformer with the help of a video on Youtube I've done everything same as him but my character refuses to move left

Tags: godot

I'm trying to make a 2d platformer in godot with help from one of the the videos. video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PG0tfoPraE4. I have very little experience working with Godot.
I'm stuck and am not sure what to do, I've tried looking at some more videos as a last resort but all of them use another way of movement.
Here is the code

GDSCRIPT

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const MOVESPEED = 70

const JUMPFORCE = -200

const GRAVITY = 600

var motion = Vector2()


func _physics_process(delta):

    if is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
            motion.y = JUMPFORCE
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x = -MOVESPEED
        $Sprite.flip_h = true
        $AnimationPlayer.play("walk")
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        motion.x = MOVESPEED 
        $Sprite.flip_h = false
        $AnimationPlayer.play("walk")
    else:
        motion.x = 0
        $AnimationPlayer.stop()
    motion.y += GRAVITY * delta


    motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2(0,-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code path is falling into the `else` clause of the right movement. So preventing it to move.
Just add and else to the right if, like:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    motion.x = -MOVESPEED
    $Sprite.flip_h = true
    $AnimationPlayer.play("walk")
elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    motion.x = MOVESPEED 
    $Sprite.flip_h = false
    $AnimationPlayer.play("walk")
else:
    motion.x = 0
    $AnimationPlayer.stop()
```